# How to use javascript history API

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, history, pushstate

In github's blog post about how they created the new tree slider, they give this as the code used:

```
$('#slider a').click(function() {
  history.pushState({ path: this.path }, '', this.href)
  $.get(this.href, function(data) {
    $('#slider').slideTo(data)      
  })
  return false  
})
```

However I don't see how this works? They AJAX request the whole new page, so from `<html>` to `</html>` inclusive, then seemingly (using a method called 'slideTo'??) put this data into the slider element? Surely then you'd end up with a page within a page (likely with CSS glitches).

How when using AJAX and History API, do you get only the specific section that has changed? Or is it that the html code is replaced (but this is not the case in the above example)?

Where is the actual javascript github uses? And am I right that the example given can't be what is used as it won't work properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The server side code could check the `X-Requested-With` header, and make sure it is `XMLHttpRequest` (jQuery sets this header by default) and send only the inner view if requested with XHR.

#### Firebug Example

[image: FireBug Example]

As you can see, the returned HTML is very different to what it would be had the request not been with XHR.

#### Example PHP Code

With a helping of self explanatory functions.

```
$xhr = (isset($_SERVER['X-Requested-With')
    AND $_SERVER['X-Requested-With'] === 'XMLHttpRequest');

$view = View::factory('inner/something');

if ( ! $xhr) {
    $view = View::factory('template')
        ->set('innerView', $view);
}

echo $view;
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I assume you know how [`pushState()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#The_pushState%28%29.c2.a0method) and [`onpopstate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onpopstate) both work.

You can use it requesting whole page, extracting part of it and replacing proper part of the currently displayed page. That way you can make smooth transition with URL change, but without page reload.

How to load part of the page? Assume on every page there is such HTML structure:

```
<div id="contentContainer">
    <div id="content">
    ...
    </div>
</div>
```

If you then make a proper request using eq. jQuery `.load()`, then it may look like this:

```
$('#contentContainer').load('index.php #content', function(){
    // some fancy animation here
});
```

What it does? It loads part of `index.php` page (actually part with `id="content"`) into currently loaded page (actually into part with `id="contentContainer"`), effectively changing only `#contentContainer` part as it would be loaded with reloading the page.

If you additionaly change URL with `pushState`, you will achieve effect as the page would be reloaded. Using `onpopstate` event, you can allow for coming back-and-forth through the dynamically generated pages.

Is it clear enough?

Using that feature you can achieve Flash-like behaviour also (smooth transitions).